# Python : element exist in list 1 and list 2

Tags: python-3.x, list

this is my code, with 2 lists. The script check the similar elements and put them in a new list named newlist :

```
list1 = ['jack sparow' , 'monika hardan', 'hamid tatan', 'california']

list2 = ['california']

newlist = []

if any(x in list1 for x in list2):
    newlist.append(list2)

print(newlist)
```

Output : `[['california']]`

What i'm looking for is, even if the element in list 1 contains one word of an element in list 2, should be detected, here is an example :

```
list1 = ['jack sparow' , 'monika hardan', 'hamid tatan', 'california']

list2 = ['sparow']

newlist = []

if any(x in list1 for x in list2):
    newlist.append(list2)

print(newlist)
```

Output : `[]`

Wanted Output : `[['jack sparow']]`

Comment: You're appending the full `list2` if any of the elements match. Is this the behavior you want?

Comment: Check the answer (and comment) of @Daniel Walker, he found the half of the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following:

```py
list1 = ['jack sparow', 'monika hardan', 'hamid tatan', 'california']

list2 = ['california', 'sparow']

newlist = [[x] for x in list1 for y in list2 if y in x]

print(newlist)
```

which prints

```
[['jack sparow'], ['california']]
```

---

**UPDATE**

To achieve the output `[['jack sparow'], [None], [None], ['california']]`, you can try the following:

```py
def is_partially_contained_in(s, t):
    for y in t:
        if y in s:
            return True
    return False


list1 = ['jack sparow', 'monika hardan', 'hamid tatan', 'california']

list2 = ['california', 'sparow']

newlist = [[x] if is_partially_contained_in(x, list2) else [None] for x in list1]

print(newlist)
```

which prints

```
[['jack sparow'], [None], [None], ['california']]
```

Comment: Thank you @Gorisanson, Is it possible to keep the ranking of the first list ?  For example, in your code, Output : [['jack sparow'], ['None'],['None], ['california']]

Answer (score 2):

```py
list1 = ['jack sparow' , 'monika hardan', 'hamid tatan', 'california']

list2 = ['california']

newlist = []

for a in list2:
    for b in list1:
        if a in b:
            newlist.append(b)

print(newlist)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if any(x in y for y in list1 for x in list2):
    newlist.append(list2)
```

Comment: this is working, but i want to append the element in list 1 , for example list 1 = jack sparow and list 2 = sparow , i want to append jack sparow

Comment: That doesn't match your desired output.  Do you want `['jack sparrow']` or `[['jack sparrow']]`?

Comment: ['jack sparrow']